# C# assembly path issue when using ReferencedAssemblies

Tags: c#, codedom

I'm trying to make a tool similar to Unity (obviously at a lower scale) and I need to be able to compile scripts which work in both the editor and the final game.

My approach to that is compiling the code in the editor using the ReferencedAssembly of my game executable, while the game executable already contains all the scripts which are present in compile time.

However I'm having a problem with the editor part. Basically I set

```
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add ("path/to/Game.exe");
parameters.GenerateInMemory=true;
parameters.GenerateExecutable=false;
```

and then compile. There are no compilation errors but when trying to use

```
var typeArray=results.CompiledAssembly.GetTypes();
```

a ReflectionTypeLoadException exception is thrown:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Game, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
```

However, copying my executable Game.exe to the tool's directory, and changing the reference assembly to

```
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add ("Game.exe");
```

allows me to compile and access to GetTypes without errors.

So, my questions are:

a) how can I make GetTypes work when using an assembly which is in another directory? (note: I'd rather not add the path to the GAC, as it should be a generic tool)

b) would it be possible to access type info without loading the referenced assembly? I mean, in NET 4.5 Type and TypeInfo are supposed to be splitted just for this reason, isn't it?

Comment: The CLR has pretty strict rules about where exactly it looks for dependent assemblies.  The odds that it is going to look in `path/to/` are zero if this is done in a "tool" and the tool is not in the same directory as game.exe.  Use Fuslogvw.exe to get insight, use the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event as a possible band-aid.  And consider that the game executable and the tools should probably not be miles apart.

Comment: @Hans, I wish I knew about [Fuslogvw.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4) before - it sounds like I could have saved myself quite a lot of trouble in the past!

Comment: Thanks Hans, the AssemblyResolve is exactly what I looking for

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your point **a)**: *"how can I make GetTypes work when using an assembly which is in another directory?*

I think you could you use [Assembly.LoadFrom Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28) to load the assembly from another directory.

Regarding your point **b)**: *"would it be possible to access type info without loading the referenced assembly?"*

I'm not sure you'd be able to access type info without loading it in **some** fashion, but are you aware of [loading Assemblies into the Reflection-Only Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172331)?

> The reflection-only load context allows you to examine assemblies compiled for other platforms or for other versions of the .NET Framework. Code loaded into this context can only be examined; it cannot be executed. This means that objects cannot be created, because constructors cannot be executed. Because the code cannot be executed, dependencies are not automatically loaded. If you need to examine them, you must load them yourself.

On a second reading of your question, how does "game.exe" get referenced in your project file?

If it's a case of MSBuild needing to copy it to the build output folder of the project, you could add "game.exe as an item in the project, set the [build action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0c6xyb66%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to "None" and the [Copy to Output Directory Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0c6xyb66%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to "Copy if newer".

Comment: Hi Wai Ha Lee, the exe is choosen in runtime as the editor must work for several projects without recompiling, so unfortunately I can't use Copy to Output. I'll check the Reflection-Only context loading as it can be an alternative way to do what I need. Thanks!